# Getting pixels from an image using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bmp

I would like to write a script that reads a bmp file and then notes the pixels on the x-y axes where the image is a color other than white. Then with this data, save it into a .txt file.

I have started using the Pillow library but haven't found how to solve this problem. I opened the bmp file with Pillow and tried to play around with the modules from Image but I couldn't find how to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read pixels with `Image.getpixel()` from PIL.

The code below will give you all non-white pixels in the form of a 2D list.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('x.bmp')

imageSizeW, imageSizeH = im.size

nonWhitePixels = []

for i in range(1, imageSizeW):
    for j in range(1, imageSizeH):
        pixVal = im.getpixel((i, j))
        if pixVal != (255, 255, 255):
            nonWhitePixels.append([i, j])

print(nonWhitePixels)
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**
Just realized, that the question was about finding the indices of all pixels which are *different* from white...
For this case just replace the calculation of the boolean array by its complement function:

```
white = (img[:, :, :3] != 255).any(2)
```

***or***

simply add a `~` in front of the boolean array in `np.where`:

```
coords = np.array(np.where(~white))[::-1].T
```

test result then would be consequently the opposite

[image]

---

Here I assume *"using PIL"* is not a strict requirement, but only a sign of how you tried to start.

That said, you can do the following, using `imread` from `imageio`:

```
import numpy as np
from imageio import imread

img = imread(filename)
white = (img[:, :, :3] == 255).all(2)
coords = np.array(np.where(white))[::-1].T
```

writing into an ascii file could be done like

```
with open('xycoordinates.txt', 'w') as f:
    for c in coords:
        f.write(f'{c[0]},{c[1]}\n')
```

***Explanation***
`img` is a 3D-array, of shape `(nr, nc, c)`, i.e. number of rows, number of columns and RGBA-values.
`img[:, :, :3] == 255` returns a boolean array of the same shape like `img`, indicating componentwise matching of the single RGB values (without respect to A. If A should be 255, too, just leave away the complete indexing brackets).
`.all(2)` reduces it to the desired array of shape `(nr, nc)` by setting only those indices to `True`, where the complete RGBA-array matches.

`np.where(white)` returns a tuple of the row- and  column-indices.
`np.array()` casts it into a numpy array in order to apply numpy indexing and transformation to it.
As `row/column` is the opposite order of a `x/y` nomenclature, `[::-1]` reverses the order of the two index arrays.
Transformation by `.T` is done to output not two arrays (`x` and `y`) of n indices, but n arrays of `(x, y)` indices.

***Example***

```
img = imread(samplefile)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

```
white = (img == [255, 255, 255, 255]).all(2)

array([[False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])

coords = np.array(np.where(white))[::-1].T

array([[2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [5, 4]], dtype=int64)

plt.plot(*coords.T, 'ro')
```

[image]